# Chrome: Div has white line in center

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

For some reason Chrome is rendering out one of my divs with a white line going straight through the middle. I provided an image below. It looks okay in Firefox hover.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="corners">
<center><h2 class="featurette-heading3">What Are BnD'z Hours Of Operation?       </h2>
</center>
<ul class=""> 
<li>Monday-Thursday 6:00AM &mdash; 9:00PM </li>
 <li>Friday 6:00AM &mdash; 10:00PM</li>
 <li>Saturday 11:00AM &mdash; 10:00PM</li>
  <li>Sunday 11:00AM &mdash; 8:00PM </li>
  <br></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.corners {
background: #cc0000; /* fallback */
background:
    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
background:
    -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -o-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
background:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
}

.corners.round {
background:#;
background:
    -moz-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
    -moz-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
    -moz-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
    -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px);
background:
     -o-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
     -o-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
     -o-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
     -o-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px);
background:
     -webkit-radial-gradient(0 100%, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
     -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
     -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px),
     -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #c00 15px);
}

.corners, .corners.round {
background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
-moz-background-size: 50% 50%;
-webkit-background-size: 50% 50%;
background-size: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.corners {
width: 500px;
margin:15px auto;
padding:13px 15px;
color: white;
line-height:1.5;
}
```

Comment: Could we see the HTML to which the CSS is applied?

Comment: @ajp15243 Updated with HTML!

Comment: Note that the [`<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML4 and obselete/non-conforming in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center). Instead, you should use something like a `<span>` (or just your `<h2>`) with CSS rules to center it.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WpQPQ/

Comment: @j08691 That's interesting, because when I copy/pasted into a fiddle (and when I looked at your fiddle), I saw a vertical bar running through the center. I got it to go away by reducing the `padding` rule on `div.corners` from `13px 15px` to `13px 10px` (it showed up again when I went to `9px`). I am using Chrome 28 on Linux with GNOME3.

Comment: I agree with @j08691 - the HTML/CSS that you presented seems to be okay: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/k7UGz/

Comment: @MarcAudet I see both a vertical *and* a horizonal bar in your fiddle.

Comment: @AoiHana What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Chorme 27 on Win7.

Comment: Both fiddles look fine in my Win7 VM with Chrome 27 (and Chrome 28, my VM's Chrome updated after I opened it).

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome 27, Win 8. Just upgraded to Chrome 28 and tested again. Still looks fine

Comment: I am using a Windows 7 computer. Tested with Firefox and the latest version of Chrome. It also had the line with a Mac using Chrome as well. Strange.

Comment: No Lines Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116, OS X 10.8.3

Comment: @AoiHana I think it has to do with how the text is rendered (text rendering is notoriously different between both browsers and OSes). On my Win7 VM, the `h2` content is on one line, but on Linux the content wraps to a second line, which is going to change the layout of that entire bit of content. I think this may be exposing a deeper potential problem with how your `div.corners` styling is constructed. Unfortunately I am not a CSS expert. Have you tried the standard, non-vendor [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) CSS function?

Comment: Derp, that should be the [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) function.

Comment: The angles are wrong, and you are missing a standard background

Comment: @ajp15243 The difference is most likely because in the example, no fonts (or font sizes) have been applied and is using the browser defaults which differ even more.  I suspect the OP has (or he should) be applying font information in the real page.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Good point, although I'm not so sure anymore that this uncovered the gradient problem you seem to have solved in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your angles are wrong.  You use 135deg where you should be using 315deg and you use 315deg where you should be using 135deg.  You see a line because you have the backgrounds ending at exactly 50% and browsers are notorious for having issues along the edge of images, and it's likely a rounding difference.

Here is the corrected CSS:

```
.corners h2 { text-align:center;}
.corners {
    background: #cc0000;
    /* fallback */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -o-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -o-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0px, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 0px, transparent 10px, #c00 10px), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 0px, transparent 10px, #c00 10px);
}

.corners, .corners.round {
    background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
    -moz-background-size: 51% 51%;
    -webkit-background-size: 51% 51%;
    background-size: 51% 51%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.corners {
    width: 500px;
    margin:15px auto;
    padding:13px 15px;
    color: white;
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="corners">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading3">What Are BnD'z Hours Of Operation?</h2>
    <ul class="">
        <li>Monday-Thursday 6:00AM &mdash; 9:00PM</li>
        <li>Friday 6:00AM &mdash; 10:00PM</li>
        <li>Saturday 11:00AM &mdash; 10:00PM</li>
        <li>Sunday 11:00AM &mdash; 8:00PM</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7UGz/9/

I've increased the background sizes so that they overlap slightly to remove issues with browsers (Chrome on Linux) not calculating out 50% precisely enough to apply full coverage.

Comment: Tested in Firefox 22.0, Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m, and IE 10.

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps 135deg and 315deg isn't switched, but the background-positions are.  In either case, they don't match.

Comment: I still see vertical and horizontal bars on Linux, but they are not present in Win7.

Comment: Nope! Gone in both Linux and Win7!

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-radial-gradient-syntax/) website leads me to believe that you should be using `background-image:` as opposed to `background:` when using radial gradients.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is wrong.  You can use background as a shortcut just fine.